# PayPal Rest API - Sandbox Recurring Subscription Webhook Notifications

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am implementing recurring subscriptions using the Paypal Rest API. In Sandbox mode, I subscribed to all Webhook events, with the the target in mind that I will receive notifications such as when the plan and agreement are created, as well as when the recurring billing takes place. Whilst I am receiving the notifications for the plan and agreement, I am not receiving any notifications for the daily billing that is supposed to take place. The 'payment_definitions' section of the: Billing Plan created notification can be seen below. It clearly states that the frequency is: Day and frequency_interval is 1.

```
"payment_definitions": [
{
    "name": "Standard Plan",
     "type": "REGULAR",
     "frequency": "Day",
     "frequency_interval": "1",
     "amount": {
         "currency": "EUR",
         "value": "40"
     },
     "cycles": "11",
     "charge_models": [],
     "id": "PD-01A711327R015545F37WM7QI"
}
],
```

I was under the impression that a notification such PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED can and should be used in the Webhook listener to extend the user's subscription on a monthly basis (I am using 'DAY' frequency just for testing purposes, for the time being).

Is this the way it should work? Perhaps, there should be no Webhook notification when the scheduled billing takes place? Perhaps such a model is what should be used: a yearly subscription is given, and if no cancelled notification takes place it is simply left to run out its course?

Or does it just not work in Sandbox, perhaps? Note than in the Webhook logs within the PayPal developer, the only notifications present are related to Billing Plan Created and Billing Subscription Created. There are several instances done on the 17th and 19th April, so there should have been at least 4 notifications of daily billing ever since.